# JQuery - insert box into wall every x time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I bought this plugin: http://goo.gl/FnMjAa

this is a social stream in a wall.

and i want to add custom massege after every x boxes.

I mean I need to to insert a box after every X Boxes.

can i do it?

Comment: Tip: try to use the modulo `%` operator

Comment: Why you bought it? This is free: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Answer (score 0):

I would use `nth-child` selector to insert something after each nth element. Consider this

```
// Insert after every 5th
$('.box:nth-child(5n)').after(function() {
    return '<div class="message">Message: after ' + $(this).data('id') + '</div>';
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/Su3c2/1/

Maybe it will work for you.

Comment: The problem in this, it's the width of the box, this is postion "absolut" and i need to insert between them